# Chern-Simons Level Quantization for non-compact groups?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

Usually for Chern-Simons theory with compact gauge group, which we can take to be $SU(2)$ for simplicity, one has that level $k$ (or coupling) has to be quantized in order for the action to be gauge invariant. If the theory is placed on a manifold with boundary, say an infinite cylinder, it is well known that the theory reduces to a level $k$ Wess-Zumino-Witten model at the boundary, and the quantization of the level on the boundary theory comes from the fact that the WZ term
\begin{equation}
w(g)= -\frac{1}{48 \pi^2}\int_{M_3} Tr[g^{-1}dg \wedge g^{-1}dg \wedge g^{-1}dg ]
\end{equation}
jumps in integer values depending on the homotopy class of the map $g: M_3 \rightarrow SU(2)$ . Now, for some noncompact groups such as $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, this is no longer true since $\pi_3(SL(2,\mathbb{R}))$ is trivial. As a result for an $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ WZW model the level need not be quantized. My question is, does this extend to Chern-Simons theory with gauge group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$? My guess would be that the level is also not quantized, since the WZ term is what one obtains after a gauge transformation, so that it is sufficient to have $k w(g)$ be quantized.

Comment: At the level of the action, $k$ need not be quantized: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104249532